# Spark Understanding Interval between jobs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In spark UI, I am wondering what is going on between jobs and looking for any ways reduce them, especially after collect and before writing parquet.
I see a really long break before submitting parquet, almost 1 minute. Considering the whole application is taking 2 minutes, it takes a great proportion. Does this break usually means sparking is going over all the workers and collecting datas? Even so, the interval before parquet is quite longer than other actions, such as collect or first.
Thanks

Here is the image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, that delay is generally present when the *driver* portion of your job is busy doing work. For instance, if you do a `.collect()`, and then iterate over the resulting `Array`, that work is being done sequentially on the *driver*, and would result in no tasks being assigned to the executors during that time.

Comment: that was my guess too, but I was confused with the bar showing collect job being done on executor. I was wondering if i call collect, what is going on with interval and the actual executor after the interval. Also to reduce the delay, what should I do? Increase driver core?

Comment: It's very hard to speculate further without some code examples. Even something as benign looking as a `.collect().toMap` can cause the driver to hang for a long time, as it iterates over the local array sequentially on the driver. If this is the case, more cores wouldn't help because it's single threaded.